# ffmpeg conversion from Flac to Ogg produces corrupted files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, ogg, flac

i transcoded flac files to ogg using this command

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -c:a libvorbis -b:a 500k  output.ogg
```

yes i use 500k to keep the highest quality possible, some of the files are ok, but some of them can not be played - *Unsupported format or corrupted file* says the foobar - also my icecast streamer cant read it. So there is something wrong with the files.

I believed it was due to the high bitrate so I tried

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -c:a libvorbis -b:a 320k  output.ogg
```

the same happened, some files were ok, some were not playable.
so I tried again with default using this command

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -c:a libvorbis output.ogg
```

same thing. some files were ok, some were corrupted and not playable.

i have no clue why.

both flac and ogg are in the same family, what happened during the transcoding that it became a corrupted file?

the spectral analysis does not show anything wrong - here it the ogg https://prnt.sc/115zdjl, here is the original flac https://prnt.sc/115zegw

i am really interested what is going on and how to make it work?

can anyone explain?

here is complete log

```
    C:\Users\lukas.kotatko>ffmpeg -i "\\192.168.0.128\lukas\online radio resources\Atma FM playlists\channel 1\flac lossless\Tuu\One Thousand Years\02 One Thousand Years.flac" -c:a libvorbis -b:a 500k "\\192.168.0.128\lukas\online radio resources\Atma FM playlists\channel 1\flac lossless\Tuu\One Thousand Years\02 One Thousand Years [500k test].ogg"
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200726
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, flac, from '\\192.168.0.128\lukas\online radio resources\Atma FM playlists\channel 1\flac lossless\Tuu\One Thousand Years\02 One Thousand Years.flac':
  Metadata:
    GENRE           : Tribal / Ambient
    ORGANIZATION    : Waveform Records
    ISRC            : 01101-2
    COMMENT         : US reissue featuring the six original tracks plus two taken from the Invocation album.
    MUSICBRAINZ_RELEASEGROUPID: 737d0518-3dc2-36b3-9419-282c0ade0e50
    ORIGINALDATE    : 1993
    ORIGINALYEAR    : 1993
    RELEASETYPE     : album
    MUSICBRAINZ_ALBUMID: f6339129-f662-43a1-93df-2f20540f73cc
    ALBUM           : One Thousand Years
    BARCODE         : 789060110125
    MUSICBRAINZ_ALBUMARTISTID: e05a42e7-60a3-4d2d-983c-51dc4eb67cad
    album_artist    : Tuu
    ALBUMARTISTSORT : Tuu
    ASIN            : B00005B9TT
    SCRIPT          : Latn
    RELEASESTATUS   : official
    LABEL           : Waveform Records
    CATALOGNUMBER   : 01101-2
    RELEASECOUNTRY  : US
    DATE            : 2001-05-08
    TOTALDISCS      : 1
    disc            : 1
    TOTALTRACKS     : 8
    MEDIA           : CD
    MUSICBRAINZ_TRACKID: aef9824d-e4a6-4ae6-aebe-50a83dd14f71
    TITLE           : One Thousand Years
    MUSICBRAINZ_ARTISTID: e05a42e7-60a3-4d2d-983c-51dc4eb67cad
    ARTIST          : Tuu
    ARTISTSORT      : Tuu
    ARTISTS         : Tuu
    MUSICBRAINZ_RELEASETRACKID: 621c9da6-a85d-3f8b-b485-5e6f74a60cd0
    track           : 2
    TRACKTOTAL      : 8
    DISCTOTAL       : 1
  Duration: 00:08:03.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 792 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 600x600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      comment         : Cover (front)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> theora (libtheora))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (flac (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0000015307581a00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[ogg @ 00000153073f1680] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
Output #0, ogg, to '\\192.168.0.128\lukas\online radio resources\Atma FM playlists\channel 1\flac lossless\Tuu\One Thousand Years\02 One Thousand Years [500k test].ogg':
  Metadata:
    GENRE           : Tribal / Ambient
    ORGANIZATION    : Waveform Records
    ISRC            : 01101-2
    COMMENT         : US reissue featuring the six original tracks plus two taken from the Invocation album.
    MUSICBRAINZ_RELEASEGROUPID: 737d0518-3dc2-36b3-9419-282c0ade0e50
    ORIGINALDATE    : 1993
    ORIGINALYEAR    : 1993
    RELEASETYPE     : album
    MUSICBRAINZ_ALBUMID: f6339129-f662-43a1-93df-2f20540f73cc
    ALBUM           : One Thousand Years
    BARCODE         : 789060110125
    MUSICBRAINZ_ALBUMARTISTID: e05a42e7-60a3-4d2d-983c-51dc4eb67cad
    album_artist    : Tuu
    ALBUMARTISTSORT : Tuu
    ASIN            : B00005B9TT
    SCRIPT          : Latn
    RELEASESTATUS   : official
    LABEL           : Waveform Records
    CATALOGNUMBER   : 01101-2
    RELEASECOUNTRY  : US
    DATE            : 2001-05-08
    TOTALDISCS      : 1
    disc            : 1
    TOTALTRACKS     : 8
    MEDIA           : CD
    MUSICBRAINZ_TRACKID: aef9824d-e4a6-4ae6-aebe-50a83dd14f71
    TITLE           : One Thousand Years
    MUSICBRAINZ_ARTISTID: e05a42e7-60a3-4d2d-983c-51dc4eb67cad
    ARTIST          : Tuu
    ARTISTSORT      : Tuu
    ARTISTS         : Tuu
    MUSICBRAINZ_RELEASETRACKID: 621c9da6-a85d-3f8b-b485-5e6f74a60cd0
    track           : 2
    TRACKTOTAL      : 8
    DISCTOTAL       : 1
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: theora (libtheora), yuv420p(progressive), 600x600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k fps, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      DESCRIPTION     : Cover (front)
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libtheora
      GENRE           : Tribal / Ambient
      ORGANIZATION    : Waveform Records
      ISRC            : 01101-2
      MUSICBRAINZ_RELEASEGROUPID: 737d0518-3dc2-36b3-9419-282c0ade0e50
      ORIGINALDATE    : 1993
      ORIGINALYEAR    : 1993
      RELEASETYPE     : album
      MUSICBRAINZ_ALBUMID: f6339129-f662-43a1-93df-2f20540f73cc
      ALBUM           : One Thousand Years
      BARCODE         : 789060110125
      MUSICBRAINZ_ALBUMARTISTID: e05a42e7-60a3-4d2d-983c-51dc4eb67cad
      ALBUMARTIST     : Tuu
      ALBUMARTISTSORT : Tuu
      ASIN            : B00005B9TT
      SCRIPT          : Latn
      RELEASESTATUS   : official
      LABEL           : Waveform Records
      CATALOGNUMBER   : 01101-2
      RELEASECOUNTRY  : US
      DATE            : 2001-05-08
      TOTALDISCS      : 1
      DISCNUMBER      : 1
      TOTALTRACKS     : 8
      MEDIA           : CD
      MUSICBRAINZ_TRACKID: aef9824d-e4a6-4ae6-aebe-50a83dd14f71
      TITLE           : One Thousand Years
      MUSICBRAINZ_ARTISTID: e05a42e7-60a3-4d2d-983c-51dc4eb67cad
      ARTIST          : Tuu
      ARTISTSORT      : Tuu
      ARTISTS         : Tuu
      MUSICBRAINZ_RELEASETRACKID: 621c9da6-a85d-3f8b-b485-5e6f74a60cd0
      TRACKNUMBER     : 2
      TRACKTOTAL      : 8
      DISCTOTAL       : 1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (16 bit), 500 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libvorbis
      GENRE           : Tribal / Ambient
      ORGANIZATION    : Waveform Records
      ISRC            : 01101-2
      DESCRIPTION     : US reissue featuring the six original tracks plus two taken from the Invocation album.
      MUSICBRAINZ_RELEASEGROUPID: 737d0518-3dc2-36b3-9419-282c0ade0e50
      ORIGINALDATE    : 1993
      ORIGINALYEAR    : 1993
      RELEASETYPE     : album
      MUSICBRAINZ_ALBUMID: f6339129-f662-43a1-93df-2f20540f73cc
      ALBUM           : One Thousand Years
      BARCODE         : 789060110125
      MUSICBRAINZ_ALBUMARTISTID: e05a42e7-60a3-4d2d-983c-51dc4eb67cad
      ALBUMARTIST     : Tuu
      ALBUMARTISTSORT : Tuu
      ASIN            : B00005B9TT
      SCRIPT          : Latn
      RELEASESTATUS   : official
      LABEL           : Waveform Records
      CATALOGNUMBER   : 01101-2
      RELEASECOUNTRY  : US
      DATE            : 2001-05-08
      TOTALDISCS      : 1
      DISCNUMBER      : 1
      TOTALTRACKS     : 8
      MEDIA           : CD
      MUSICBRAINZ_TRACKID: aef9824d-e4a6-4ae6-aebe-50a83dd14f71
      TITLE           : One Thousand Years
      MUSICBRAINZ_ARTISTID: e05a42e7-60a3-4d2d-983c-51dc4eb67cad
      ARTIST          : Tuu
      ARTISTSORT      : Tuu
      ARTISTS         : Tuu
      MUSICBRAINZ_RELEASETRACKID: 621c9da6-a85d-3f8b-b485-5e6f74a60cd0
      TRACKNUMBER     : 2
      TRACKTOTAL      : 8
      DISCTOTAL       : 1
frame=    1 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 Lsize=   25860kB time=00:08:03.66 bitrate= 438.0kbits/s speed=44.6x
video:8kB audio:25721kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:7kB muxing overhead: 0.511663%
```

Comment: Show the complete log from command #3.

Comment: @llogan is correct, a log would be helpful. Another test could also be to simply -b:a copy to see if you get the same results

Comment: i attached the complete log

Comment: Try omitting the album art: `ffmpeg -i input.flac -c:a libvorbis -map 0:a output.ogg`, or stream copying it `ffmpeg -i input.flac -c:v copy -c:a libvorbis output.ogg`

Answer (score 0):

what I am trying to achieve is to stream hi res lossless flac files. I seem to get be getting there.

this command `ffmpeg -i input.flac output.ogg` makes a lossy ogg file. it shrinks the size drastically and produces a file with a bitrate around 128 k.
the spectral analysis shows details https://prnt.sc/117904c - quite terrible. all above 17 kHz is gone forever + other "non-hearable" sound is gone forever as well. Even with -b:a option `ffmpeg -i input.flac -b:a 320k output.ogg` it will still be lossy file, just with a higher bitrate. maximum -b:a is 500k as far as i know.. already pretty accurate, but still a lossy file.

but this command `ffmpeg -i input.flac  -c:a libvorbis -c:a copy -map 0:a output.ogg` actually works. It wraps flac to ogg container so that it is better for streaming, keeping all the lossless quality. See [Why is FLAC Streaming over HTTP done with Ogg encapsulation instead of natively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489300/why-is-flac-streaming-over-http-done-with-ogg-encapsulation-instead-of-natively)

I seem to be finally figuring out how to prepare flac files to lossless hi res stream. all it needs is to wrap them into ogg container with this command.

> `ffmpeg -i input.flac  -c:a libvorbis -c:a copy -map 0:a  output.ogg`

the spectral analysis proves that it actually is the lossless file even though it has .ogg extension:
here is the wrapper ogg flac file https://prnt.sc/1178jp4 and here is the original flac file https://prnt.sc/1178l8h.

now I need to test it with multiple files and see how Icecast server handles the lossless stream

Comment: ok so another update here.. seems like Icecast cannot read such a hi-res file.. giving this error.  `EROR input/input_calculate_ogg_sleep Timing control: can't determine sample rate for input, not Vorbis.`  but they are ogg files and they can be easily played in any player, so what is the problem.. ? who knows?